# Submit multiple rows of unique info into MySQL database in one query

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have been scanning other similar questions but I'm just not having any luck.

Here is my existing page: http://excelwrestling.com/dual.php

You will see on the web page that the bottom three lines are the same on the form, but each line will have unique information.  I am trying to have the user select each box then when they hit submit it will send all the info to the database, with each row being unique.

```
Here a sample of my html:

    <select name="Weight">

<option value="Weight">Weight:</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="105">105</option>
        <option value="115">115</option>
        <option value="125">125</option>
        <option value="135">135</option>
        <option value="145">145</option>
        <option value="152">152</option>
        <option value="160">160</option>
        <option value="175">175</option>
        <option value="195">195</option>
        <option value="HWT">HWT</option>
        </select>
</select>

Here is the action file:

// Get values from form 
$Pool=$_POST['Pool'];
$Round=$_POST['Round'];
$Team_1=$_POST['Team_1'];
$Team_2=$_POST['Team_2'];
$Mat=$_POST['Mat'];
$Name_1=$_POST['Name_1'];
$Name_2=$_POST['Name_2'];
$Score=$_POST['Score'];
$Winner=$_POST['Winner'];
$Finished=$_POST['Finished'];


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Pool, Round, Team_1, Team_2, Mat, Weight, Name_1, Name_2, Score, Winner, Finished)

VALUES('$Pool','$Round','$Team_1','$Team_2','$Mat','$Weight','$Name_1','$Name_2','$Score','$Winner','$Finished')"

. implode ('$Pool','$Round','$Team_1','$Team_2','$Mat','$Weight','$Name_1','$Name_2','$Score','$Winner','$Finished',$query_row);
```

Comment: What exactly is the schema of your database?  Can you show us the output of `desc tbl_name`?

Comment: Hello, is this wanting to see?  http://excelwrestling.com/showresults.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to create unique names for your form elements in order to have more than one value submitted. e.g.:

```
<option value="Weight_1">Weight:</option>
...
<option value="Weight_2">Weight:</option>
...
<option value="Weight_3">Weight:</option>
```

In the "action" file, you will need to reference these new variables (and you should also sanitize your user posted data before insertion into the table as technoTarek says):

```
$Weight_1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Weight_1']);
$Weight_2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Weight_2']);
$Weight_3=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Weight_3']);
...
```

And then, to do multiple insert into the same table, you can simply separate the records with a comma:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name
(Pool, Round, Team_1, Team_2, Mat, Weight, Name_1, Name_2, Score, Winner, Finished)
VALUES
('$Pool','$Round','$Team_1','$Team_2','$Mat','$Weight_1','$Name_1_1','$Name_2_1','$Score_1','$Winner_1','$Finished_1'),
('$Pool','$Round','$Team_1','$Team_2','$Mat','$Weight_2','$Name_1_2','$Name_2_2','$Score_2','$Winner_2','$Finished_2'),
('$Pool','$Round','$Team_1','$Team_2','$Mat','$Weight_3','$Name_1_3','$Name_2_3','$Score_3','$Winner_3','$Finished_3');"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Will creating all those separate names give me one long row though, instead of inputting the data in the existing (Pool, Round, Team_1, etc.) columns? I'm a newby, so I could most definitely be wrong.

Comment: If it helps, this is the table I am trying to put the data into: http://excelwrestling.com/showresults.php

Comment: Actually, as I look at it again, pool,round,team_1,team_2 and mat do not need to be unique for each record, only the values starting at weight (where the values need to be different for each record). I'll edit that.

Comment: The insert statement will insert 3 separate rows, not one long row. I think that's what you were asking.

Comment: That worked!! Now it creates 3 rows when I click submit.  But how do I get it to show the data?  Here is what I have on the /showresults.php page.

Comment: <?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Pool");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Round");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"Team_1");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"Team_2");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"Mat");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Weight""");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"Name_1");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"Name_2");

Comment: $f9=mysql_result($result,$i,"Score");
$f10=mysql_result($result,$i,"Winner");
$f11=mysql_result($result,$i,"Finished");

?>

Comment: <tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>

Comment: td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f9; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f10; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f11; ?></font></td>

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I tried to put in the other unique form names in the variable area, but all that did was clear all the data from the results page: http://excelwrestling.com/showresults.php example: $f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Weight","Weight_2","Weight_3");

Comment: That is terribly difficult to read, but I would guess that some of the values aren't being stored in the table (based on looking at your results page). The problem is likely due to the middle section of your code, which I omitted from my solution. You will need to update all of the lines similar to `$Name_1=$_POST['Name_1'];` to reflect the new variables (e.g. `$Name_1_1=$_POST['Name_1_1'];`, `$Name_1_2=$_POST['Name_1_2']`, etc.)

Comment: Good catch, I just updated those but I am still getting zero results in my table from any of the variables other than the beginning ones that didn't need to be replicated.  Do you know what could be causing that?  Do I need to create Name_1_2, Name_2_2, etc. in my database for it to work?

Comment: No, because they are being stored as separate rows. Problem could be the line `$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Weight"""); `. Not sure what's up with the extra quotes.

Comment: Just saw your other comment: `$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Weight","Weight_2","Weight_3");` is wrong, and is likely the problem. Once the data is in the database, the only valid column name would be `Weight`. The others are just variables used in the form.

Comment: Wow, the "" in the "Weight" category threw it all off. The results are now showing!!  You are a great person for helping me.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

do not try to insert all record at once just try to insert record using loop or one record at a time using foreach statement.

then this will solve your problem.

Comment: Only if I knew how to do that! haha

Answer (score 0):

I generally support the answer provided by @mmxxiii ...but it should include one VERY IMPORTANT step. You should ALWAYS make sure your data is safe before you insert into the database, even if you are the one entering the data.

SANITIZE THE DATA by using either mysql_real_escape_string() on string values or by forcing a type cast (e.g., forcing an integer value to be an integer).

```
// Get values from form 
$Pool=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Pool']);
$Round=(int)$_POST['Round'];
$Team_1=(int)$_POST['Team_1'];
$Team_2=(int)$_POST['Team_2'];
$Mat=(int)$_POST['Mat'];
$Name_1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name_1']);
$Name_2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name_2']);
$Score=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Score']);
$Winner=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Winner']);
$Finished=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Finished']);
```

Comment: Yes. One should **always** sanitize user submitted data.

Comment: @technoTarek if you are the one that entered "Check stackoverflow" in the pool section, you are brilliant.  I have no idea how you did that, but I definitely going to sanitize the data haha!

Comment: It wasn't me, but not sanitizing your queries per my post is what made it possible. I suggest you google and read about SQL injection. One could likely cause far more harm than the sprinkling of unwanted data that you saw. Good luck.